# how to add argument to sbatch in dask jobqueue?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

The SLURM cluster I am working on, jobs need to be submitted with

```bash
sbatch -C gpu script.sh
```

Do you know how to add `-C gpu` flag in the Dask Python script?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster
from dask.distributed import Client

# Create a SLURM cluster with 2 nodes, 8 cores per node
cluster = SLURMCluster(
    queue='myjob',
    cores=8,
    memory='20GB',
    account='my_account_info',
    walltime='01:00:00',
    job_extra_directives=['--partition=normal', # debug 
                          '--constraint=gpu',
                          '--ntasks-per-core=2',
                          '--ntasks-per-node=12',
                          '--output=log.log',
                          '--error=error.log'],
    job_script_prologue=[
        'export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK',
        'export CRAY_CUDA_MPS=1',
        'module load daint-gpu',
        'module load cray-python',
        'source /users/my_username/my_env/bin/activate']
)

# Scale the cluster to 16 workers
cluster.scale(16)

# Connect a Dask client to the cluster
client = Client(cluster)

# Define a function to be executed on each worker
def my_function(x):
    return x ** 2

# Submit a bunch of jobs to the cluster
futures = []
for i in range(100):
    future = client.submit(my_function, i)
    futures.append(future)

# Wait for the jobs to complete and get the results
results = client.gather(futures)
print(results)
```

The code requests 2 nodes with 8 cores each and runs a sample function to print an integer.
I don't also know how to print the created script to check is everything is how I expect it to be.
Do you have any idea?